# Google Cloud Armor

Tags: google-cloud-armor

I want to create new Cloud Armor policy for my website to prevent DDOS attack, which is hosted on GCP VM.
So how do I prevent & configure from tcp , udp flood & ICMP. Also what are the IP's to put in to blacklist.

Please suggest me,
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to the [official doucumentation](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/security-policy-overview)

> Google Cloud Armor security policies **are available only for backend services behind an external HTTP(S) load balancer**.

> Google Cloud Armor security policies are made up of rules that filter traffic based on layer 3, 4, and 7 attributes. For example, you can specify conditions that match on an **incoming request's IP address, IP range, region code, or request headers**.

You can find a detailed explanation here:

[Configuring Google Cloud Armor security policies](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/configure-security-policies)

Answer (score 0):

@Vittal

Regarding the last part of your question ( as the first part already answered ): "Also what are the IP's to put on to blacklist."

What to block is absolutely based on your business. But if your project is already a part of the "Adaptive Protection Plan", then you can use GCP Threat Intelligence PreConfigured rules like :

1. Blocking ToR Network. 2) Blocking Crawlers and Search Engine IP's 3) Blocking iplist-search-engines-crawlers

You can find more of these thread detection rules from the below article:
https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/threat-intelligence#configure-nti

Thanks
Manoj